# I have a problem with my database UPDATE query in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, database, mysqli

## a bit of intro

So I'm new to this kind of work and  I'm making on a page for admins where there's database information regarding employees, projects...etc organized into tables with buttons to either >>> **DELETE** or **UPDATE** the user(in this case ) the update function wont work !!

so the 2 "buttons" are actually  using `<a>` and `onclick` to call either `myAjaxDelete` or `myAjaxAdd` ( i'm not that familiar with ajax btw ) to call php file, passing data in from `hidden input`  fields
the **DELETE** button ( or  a tag )  seems to work just fine but **UPDATE** wont 
i tried changing my sqli query and testing on signle fields but in vain

updateDbUt.php:

```
<?php 
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","gestion");
    if($_POST['action'] == 'call'){
        $id=$_POST['name'];

        $np=unserialize($_POST['np']);
        $adr=unserialize($_POST['adr']);
        $ntel=unserialize($_POST['tel']);
        $cin=unserialize($_POST['cin']);
        $pass=unserialize($_POST['pass']);
        $idEquipe=unserialize($_POST['idEquipe']);
        $mail=unserialize($_POST['mail']);
        $role=unserialize($_POST['role']);

        $q = "UPDATE `gestion`.`utilisateurs` SET `np` = '$np', `adr` ='$adr', `numTel` = '$ntel', `cin` = '$cin', `pass` = '$^pass', `idEquipe` = 'idEquipe', `adrElectronique` = '$mail', `role` = '$role' WHERE `utilisateurs`.`id` = '$id'";
        $r=mysqli_query($conn, $q);
        if ( !(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)==0 ) ) {

            echo "updated";
        } else {

        die("problem updating ").mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
 ?>
```

the script :

```
function myAjaxAdd() {
      $.ajax({
           method:'POST',
           url: 'updateDbUt.php',
           data:{
              action:'call',
              name: $('#id').serialize(),
              np: $('#np').serialize(),
              adr: $('#adr').serialize(),
              tel: $('#tel').serialize(),
              cin: $('#cin').serialize(),
              mail: $('#mail').serialize(),
              idEquipe: $('#idEquipe').serialize(),
              pass: $('#pass').serialize(),
              role: $('#role').serialize(),
            },
           success:function(html) {
             alert(html);
           }

      });
 }

</script>
```

and this is the HTML code just in case :

```
  <form method="POST">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nom Prenom</th>
                        <th>Adresse</th>
                        <th>N°Tel</th>
                        <th>Cin</th>
                        <th>ID Utilisateur</th>
                        <th>ID Equipe</th>
                        <th>adresse electronique</th>
                        <th>pass</th>
                        <th>role</th>
                        <th>actions </th>
                      </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php

                          $sql="SELECT * FROM utilisateurs";
                          $q=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                            while ($t=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {

                          ?>
                          <tr>
                            <td> <?php echo $t['np']; $np=$t['np']; ?> <input type="hidden" name="np" id="np" <?php echo "value='".$np."'"; ?> > </td>
                            <td> <?php echo $t['adr'];  $adr=$t['adr'];?> <input type="hidden" name="adr" id="adr" <?php echo "value='".$adr."'"; ?> ></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $t['numTel']; $numTel=$t['numTel']; ?> <input type="hidden" name="tel" id="tel" <?php echo "value='".$numTel."'"; ?> ></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $t['cin']; $cin=$t['cin']; ?> <input type="hidden" name="cin" id="cin" <?php echo "value='".$cin."'"; ?> ></td>

                            <td> <?php echo $t['id'];  $id=$t['id'];?> <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" <?php echo "value='".$id."'" ?>></td>

                            <td> <?php echo $t['idEquipe'];  $idEquipe=$t['idEquipe'];?> <input type="hidden" name="idEquipe" id="idEquipe" <?php echo "value='".$idEquipe."'"; ?> ></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $t['adrElectronique'];  $mail=$t['adrElectronique'];?> <input type="hidden" name="mail" id="mail" <?php echo "value='".$mail."'"; ?> ></td>
                             <td> <?php echo $t['pass'];  $pass=$t['pass']; ?> <input type="hidden" name="pass" id="pass" <?php echo "value='".$pass."'"; ?> ></td>
                             <td> <?php echo $t['role'];  $role=$t['role']; ?> <input type="hidden" name="role" id="role" <?php echo "value='".$role."'"; ?> ></td>

                            <td>
                              <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="myAjaxAdd()">
                                <i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i>
                              </a>
                              <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip" >
                                <i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i>
                              </a>
                              <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="myAjaxDelete()">
                                <i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i>
                              </a>
                            </td>
                        </td>
                          </tr>
                          <?php
                            }
                           ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

the final result is it alerting my **Update error** msg 
it shoudld've updated the database  instead
please i need help

Also : i'm testing using wampserver

Comment: _...it alerting my Update error msg_ What does it say?

Comment: @B001ᛦ it just display the `die` msg which is " problem updating"  and nothing else coming from `mysqli_error()`

Comment: Change `die("problem updating ").mysqli_error($conn);` to `die("problem updating ".mysqli_error($conn));` to see the error... or just `die(mysqli_error())`

Comment: @B001ᛦ same thing `mysqli_error()` wont display the error

Comment: php and javascript's `serialize()` / `unserialize()` functions are completely unrelated and do completely different things. You will want to serialize your form - not the individual values - in javascript and not use it at all in php. There you only need a prepared statement to bind the values.

Comment: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` add this to your code to see more MySQL error if there are any.

Comment: @jeroen I see i didn't pay attention to that, like I said my ajax knowledge is very limited so can you please include the code about serializing the form ?

Comment: @catcon it  just added a **1** in front of my msg

Comment: @jeroen at first i wasn't using the  `serialize()` i was using `.val()` but trying to get them in **updateDbUt.php** it says  _Undefined Index:_

Comment: Sorry, there is just too much wrong here, you are also overwritting you inputs as for all rows you are using the same name.

Comment: @jeroen thanks for your reply, i think i'll drop the idea of  a single page application then  and make the update button redirect to another page where a classic `action` does the job

Answer (score 0):

As a first step you need to fix your query because its wrong

```
$q = "UPDATE `gestion`.`utilisateurs` SET `np` = '$np', `adr` ='$adr', `numTel` = '$ntel', `cin` = '$cin', `pass` = '$^pass', `idEquipe` = 'idEquipe', `adrElectronique` = '$mail', `role` = '$role' WHERE `utilisateurs`.`id` = '$id'";
```

you are passing $^pass not $pass and idEquipe not $idEquipe
 a correct query would be

```
$q = "UPDATE `gestion`.`utilisateurs` SET `np` = '$np', `adr` ='$adr', `numTel` = '$ntel', `cin` = '$cin', `pass` = '$pass', `idEquipe` = '$idEquipe', `adrElectronique` = '$mail', `role` = '$role' WHERE `utilisateurs`.`id` = '$id'";
```

second i suggest you display your query and execute it in phpmyadmin since you are working with wampserver

Comment: thanks for noticing that, I did correct those but didn't work either, also the query was taken from wamp server i previously tested a query i wrote but didn't work so i copied a php source from phpmyadmin

Comment: you should print the $q variable and run it in phpmyadmin because you may be missing a field or some field types are incompatible with the values in your query